# Kinect v2 SDK Gesture Database

Tags: c#, gesture, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I am writing a Kinect application with the Kinect SDK v2 and I have a need to detect a swipe left and a swipe right gesture. To me, these gestures seem fairly standard and I would be surprised if I had to go through the whole faff of recording my own in the Visual Gesture Builder application.

I have checked out the Kinect.Toolbox here: https://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/ which contains support for the gestures I need but unfortunately it only works with the old version of the SDK.

Does anyone know of an update/rewrite to the Kinect Toolbox which would be compatible with v2 of the SDK or if there is some repository of .gdb Gesture Database files which I can download or is the only option to use the Visual Gesture Builder? So far, my day of Googling has yielded little.